# How to politely reply to: "I hope it didn’t cause you too much trouble."

Tags: word-usage, expressions

I've been emailing to someone who caused me trouble by sending me wrong answer. In the next email, he replied with "I hope it didn't cause you too much trouble." And I've been wondering how to politely answer. He did cause some trouble but nothing serious or unmanageable.

Comment: Hello Zuzana, this sort of question isn't in [our remit](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  You may get on better at [interpersonal.se], but be sure to check their help centre too.

Comment: The thing about email is: you don't have to respond (alternative 1). You could also tell the truth ("nothing serious or unmanageable" as alternative 2). You could also politely lie ("no trouble at all" as alternative 3). Perhaps ask yourself: what kind of relationship would you like to have with this person in the future?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is too open-ended and open to opinion; as a valid request, it is a better fit on Interpersonal Skills.SE